# The blank final field seed may not have been initialized

Tags: java

So I'm trying to set a default memory size and create an array of heuristics, but I keep getting the error "The blank final field seed may not have been initialised".  The aoHeuristics is an array of Heuristics. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
public class zoo_Problem extends ProblemDomain implements Visualisable {

    private final long seed;

    public int defaultSize;

    private HeuristicInterface[] aoHeuristics;

    public zoo_Problem(long seed, int defaultSize) {

         super(seed);

         this.defaultSize = 5;

         int[][] aoHeuristics = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `ProblemDomain` look like? And you do want the same `seed` in both places? I suspect you shouldn't have added a second seed to `zoo_Problem`, but without seeing `ProblemDomain` I'm just guessing. You **could** add `this.seed = seed;` after `super(seed);` and leave that for another day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise the `final` field. Add this line to the constructor:

```
     this.seed = seed;
```

Given the you are passing `seed` to the superclass constructor, you may wish to remove the field instead.

As for `aoHeuristics`, you will need to create new objects of the appropriate type for each element in the array, as well as creating the array and assigning it to the field.

The language does not require the field `aoHeuristics` to be assigned as it is not `final` - it'll just be `null` and you'll get a `NullPointerException` whenever you try to dereference it.